# bashrc doesn't run automatically

Tags: bash, ubuntu-18.04, ros

I added some commadlines at the bottom of bashrc file

```
#set ROS melodic
source /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash
source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash

#set ROS network
export ROS_HOSTNAME=localhost
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://${ROS_HOSTNAME}:11311

#set ROS alias command
alias set_roscore='source /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash'
alias cw='cd ~/catkin_ws'
alias cs='cd ~/catkin_ws/src'
alias cm='cd ~/catkin_ws && catkin_make'
```

these command lines doesn't run when I open new terminal window.

source /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash

source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash

Comment: Check this https://askubuntu.com/questions/64387/cannot-successfully-source-bashrc-from-a-shell-script

Comment: Are you sure that only the 1st 2 lines are not executed ? What does `echo $ROS_HOSTNAME` or `type set_roscore` show in your terminal ?

Comment: How do you open a terminal ? depending on the terminal, other startup script (or no startup script) may get executed.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I tested each lines and found 
source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash # this line didn't executed properly

Comment: I checked every lines executed well except 2nd line.

Comment: So it is only `source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` that does not run properly? What happens when you run it manually?